# Chrome input caching too slow

Tags: javascript

I have a website which has 3 select boxes at the top. These select boxes are used as filters for a table I am displaying underneath it. When you change something on the select box I filter the table.

If I change the select box values and go to a new page and hit the back arrow at the top and return to the same page all of my select boxes changes are still there. However, the filter that I applied to the tables using javascript does not match the filter displayed. The table displays data for the default filters.

I though if I just run the filter function on page load, things would work again. But turns out the filter function runs way before chrome resets the value of the select boxes from the cache. When I set the breakpoint and started debugging the progression on returning back to page is:

```
 1. The select boxes resets to default values (i.e the order of the `<option>` tag)
 2. The table filters based on the default values
 3. Chrome at some point decides to readd the filter
```

How do you guys deal with this?

Comment: Could you provide the code?

Comment: So onload run the code that those select boxes normally trigger if they have a value.